# Atmel run solution - Failed to launch. Missing file: AssemblerApplication1.obj

Tags: assembly, atmel, atmelstudio

For a school task, I have to write a simple assembly application in Atmel Studio 6.0. It can build without any problems, but when I try to run it, it returns the following error:
14:46:11: [ERROR] Failed to launch. Missing file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Atmel Studio\AssemblerApplication1\AssemblerApplication1\Debug\AssemblerApplication1.obj

I have no experience with assembly whatsoever, and I am unable to find anyone struggling with the same problem.